# Is there a bulk method of doing 301 redirects from old nodes to new node pages?

Tags: 7, redirection, path-aliases

I am updating an old drupal 7 site and many of the old nodes now have newer counter parts with new nodes. Since alot of my old nodes have already been spider-ed, I want to do a 301 redirect to the new nodes. I'm currently doing it manually by deleting the old node and then copying the URL alias into the [redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module and redirect it to the new node path. Is there a easier way to do this if I have 1000 nodes that need redirection?

Comment: Perhaps you mean 301 redirect?

Comment: I assume the [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you are looking for is 301 (Moved Permanently) not 403 (Forbidden). 4XX codes do not redirect.

Comment: your right. i meant 301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Global Redirect module, I think it will do what you are looking for.

http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect

Also have a look at this module it is rely handy it searches Google for inbound links to the site.
https://drupal.org/project/google301

Comment: nice find on the google301! ;)

Comment: Ya its rely handy, it saves a lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect Module + Path redirect import Module**

The module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) has great options, one of which creates redirects when you rename a page and hence change an alias.

The module [Path redirect import](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect_import) works with Redirect and allows you to upload a CSV of redirects (or use Drush), it even checks if a page you are redirecting to exists.